# Value of a determinant involving logarithmic, algebraic and trigonometric functions

Tags: derivatives, determinant

If $D(x) = \begin{vmatrix}
x&(1+x^2)&x^3\\
\log(1+x^2)&e^x&\sin(x)\\
\cos(x)&\tan(x)&\sin^2(x)\\
\end{vmatrix}$, then
find the correct option.

(a) $D(x)$ is divisible by $x$
(b) $D(x) = 0$
(c) $\frac{d}{dx}D(x) = 0$
(d) None of these

I just found that the correct option is (a).

My attempt: Elaborate expansion of the given determinant is not helping towards the solution. I wonder if there is an elegant way to solve this question. Any hint would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would say <del>(d)</del>(a).

1. To check "divisibility" by $x$, <del>you'll ignore the terms which is the multiple of $x^m$ and focus on terms which don't seem to be a multiple of $x$, expand it to find out the divisibility.  In this case, expand the determinant along the first row, and only look at $1+x^2$.  The corresponding minor matrix doesn't not have any entries which are polynomial with respect to the variable $x$, so it's in the form $\require{cancel}\cancel{(\textit{elementary functions})x^2+(\textit{elementary functions})\cdot1}$, which is *not* a multiple of $x$</del>.  Observe that the third column is "divisible" by $x$ in the sense of analytic functions  (as @Hans point out) since $\sin x=x+o(x^2)$.
2. I'm going to disprove (c).  Once we have disproved (c), we will know that $D(x)$ is *not* a constant, so (b) will be wrong.
3. Since you ask for "elegant" solution, explicit numerical solution *won't* satisfy you.  As a result, I invite you to think the behaviour of $|D(x)|$ as $x \to \pi/2^-$. ($x < \pi/2$ and $x\to\pi/2$) Except $\tan x$, the entries of the matrix are continuous at $\pi/2$, so is bounded as $x \in (\pi/2-\delta,\pi/2)$ for some small $\delta>0$.  Consider the expansion of the determinant along the third row.  The term containing $\tan(x)$ goes to $\infty$, while the other two terms are *bounded*.  From this, we conclude that $|D(x)|\to\infty$ as $x\to\pi/2^-$, so $D(x)$ is *not* constant.
4. <del>That's the only remaining choice.</del> (a) is correct in the sense of analytic functions.

Comment: I think by "divisible by" a complex (real) valued function means the ratio is an analytic function in whatever domain under consideration. So (a) is correct.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for your comment.  This makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

a) By substituting $\sin x=x\text{ sinc}(x)$, where $\text{sinc}$ is everywhere finite, you can pull out a factor $x$.

b, c) For $x=k\pi$, the matrix is triangular and the product of the diagonal is not constant*.

d) See a).

---

*Piecewise constant would rule out c) anyway.

Comment: @GNUSupporter: make things as simple as possible, but not simpler. [Albert E.]